# UDP read missing packets

Tags: python-3.x, udp

I am writing a program, which, among few other things, can receive GPS NMEA sentences over UDP.
While I am receiving datas, I know that I'm missing packets. GPS is sending every second a sequence of ZDA(time), VTG(course and speed), GGA (WGS84 position) as per screengrab:
[GPS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Ns7.png)

However, with the class I wrote, I am missing packets, but can't figure why. ZDA a well received every second, but not VTG and GGA telegrams. Here is my output:

```
['$GPZDA,204622.00,16,10,2023,,*63', '']
['$GPZDA,204623.00,16,10,2023,,*62', '']
['$GPZDA,204624.00,16,10,2023,,*65', '']
['$GPZDA,204625.00,16,10,2023,,*64', '']
['$GPZDA,204626.00,16,10,2023,,*67', '']
['$GPZDA,204627.00,16,10,2023,,*66', '']
['$GPZDA,204628.00,16,10,2023,,*69', '']
['$GPZDA,204629.00,16,10,2023,,*68', '']
['$GPZDA,204630.00,16,10,2023,,*60', '']
['$GPZDA,204631.00,16,10,2023,,*61', '']
['$GPZDA,204632.00,16,10,2023,,*62', '']
['$GPGGA,204632.00,2918.75039,N,09435.22487,W,5,26,0.6,33.64,M,-27.60,M,010,0481*53', '']
['$GPZDA,204633.00,16,10,2023,,*63', '']
['$GPZDA,204634.00,16,10,2023,,*64', '']
['$GPZDA,204635.00,16,10,2023,,*65', '']
['$GPZDA,204636.00,16,10,2023,,*66', '']
['$GPZDA,204637.00,16,10,2023,,*67', '']
['$GPZDA,204638.00,16,10,2023,,*68', '']
['$GPZDA,204639.00,16,10,2023,,*69', '']
['$GPZDA,204640.00,16,10,2023,,*67', '']
['$GPZDA,204641.00,16,10,2023,,*66', '']
['$GPZDA,204642.00,16,10,2023,,*65', '']
['$GNVTG,286.931,T,286.931,M,0.198,N,0.367,K,D*3A', '']
['$GPZDA,204643.00,16,10,2023,,*64', '']
```

My UDP_socket class:

```
class UDP_socket(object):
    ''' mode = "utf8" or "binary" '''
    def __init__(self, host='', port=0, broadcast=True, mode='utf8'):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.broadcast = broadcast
        self.mode = mode
    
    def read(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
            if self.broadcast:
                s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
            s.bind((self.host, self.port))
            if self.mode == 'binary':
                data = s.recv(1024).hex()
            else:
                data = s.recv(1024).decode('Utf8', 'replace').split('\r\n')
                print(data)
            return data

    def send(self, input, target):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
            if self.broadcast:
                s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
            s.bind((self.host, self.port))
            s.sendto(input.encode('Utf8'), target)
```

and from my GPS class:

```
    def connect_socket(self):
        '''Create a socket UDP or TCP'''
        self.continuous_read = True
        self.button.configure(text="Disconnect", command=self.socket_stop)
        if self.tcpudp.get(): #0 for TCP
            # print(self.gps_address.get(), int(self.gps_port.get()))
            self.socket = UDP_socket(self.gps_address.get(), int(self.gps_port.get()), True)
        else:
            self.socket = TCP_socket(self.gps_address.get(), int(self.gps_port.get()) )
        self.gps_marker = Map_Marker(app.map, color = self.marker_color)
        readT = threading.Thread(target= lambda: self.socket_read(FALSE))
        readT.start()

    def socket_read(self, terminal):
        telegram = nmea_oi()
        while self.continuous_read:
            received_msg = self.socket.read()
            del received_msg[-1]
            for j in range(len(received_msg)):
                if telegram.decode(received_msg[j], 'All', terminal)[0] == 'GGA':
                    lat = telegram.decode(received_msg[j], 'All', terminal)[1][0]
                    long = telegram.decode(received_msg[j], 'All', terminal)[1][1]
                    self.gps_marker.update_marker(lat, long)
                self.update_displayed_lines(received_msg[j])
```

It might looks a bit child-ich, but I am quite new to python - and object programming. I'm trying to write everything myself, to experiment and learn. Everything works for far except those missing packets.

I tried different thing like increase buffer size to 2048.
I do not use any delay. By using a software to visualize received packets on the same computer, no dropped telegrams. Has to be my code...
Could it be a Thread issue, or some timing ?

I know UDP is not to be taken as reliable, however, this is the current setup on the ship. GPS data are broadcasted over UDP, all software using this output are not missing any packet (I am talking about 15+ machines). On many of those machines, no GGA input for 10s would raise an alarm and  this never happens

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You are creating a new socket per read, and also per write. You are also leaking them. Create ONE socket for the life of the process and use it for both reading and writing. But there will always be UDP packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed ! thanks for your help.

I modified the UDP class:

```
class UDP_socket(object):
    ''' mode = "utf8" or "binary" '''
    def __init__(self, host='', port=0, broadcast=True, mode='utf8'):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.broadcast = broadcast
        self.mode = mode
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        if self.broadcast:
            self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
            self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def read(self):
        
        if self.mode == 'binary':
            data = self.s.recv(1024).hex()
        else:
            data = self.s.recv(1024).decode('Utf8', 'replace').split('\r\n')
            print(data)
        return data

    def send(self, input, target):
        self.s.sendto(input.encode('Utf8'), target)

    def close(self):
        self.s.close()
```